# How to export proto file from grpc code first project?

Tags: c#, grpc-c#

I want to define my contract with C# code first approach, something like below

```
using ProtoBuf.Grpc;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Shared.Contracts;

[DataContract]
public class HelloReply
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class HelloRequest
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IGreeterService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<HelloReply> SayHelloAsync(HelloRequest request,
        CallContext context = default);
}
```

So I want to export proto file from this (for example: for putting this contract to other teams), but I do not how to doing this?

Comment: @dan-kli export `.proto` files for many purpose such as share between many teams (in different languages) and deliver to customer, and saving in PMO as project documentations.

Comment: My company is same with your company, I need to share protobuf files with customers, so How to export protobuf files from C# code first contract?